# Meteor Redirect after login and logout

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a Meteor app and I would like to have users to go to a dashboard (called documentsIndex) page after signin and after signout, redirect them to the frontpage of the webapplication. Right now I have the following:

```
Iron.Router.hooks.requireLogin = function () {
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
    if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      this.render('this.loadingTemplate');
    } else {
      this.render('accessDenied');
    }
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

Iron.Router.hooks.goToDashboard = function () {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    Router.go('documentsIndex');
    this.next();
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

Iron.Router.hooks.goToFrontpage= function () {
  if (!Meteor.user()) {
    Router.go('frontpage');
    this.next();
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction('goToDashboard', {except: ['documentNew', 'documentIndex', 'documentShow', 'documentEdit']});
Router.onBeforeAction('goToFrontpage', {except: ['frontpage', 'about']});
Router.onBeforeAction('requireLogin', {except: ['frontpage', 'about']});
Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {only: ['documentIndex','documentNew', 'documentIndex', 'documentShow', 'documentEdit']});
```

This works, so when a user is signing in, he is always redirected to the DocumentsIndex route and he can navigate the backend. When a user is signed out, he is redirected to the frontpage and can browse the frontend.

1. This gets difficult to manage when my webapp will grow in the future (especially with the only and except statements in the onBeforeAction is will become confusing and error prone). So ideally I would like to combine everything in the requireLogin hook.
2. Later on I will work with roles (alanning:roles). I will have an 'admin' role, a registered 'customer' role and then just a normal visitor that can only access the frontpage. Any ideas of using this role in the Router hooks? An example would be more than appreciated.

Note: Im using accounts-password package

Comment: Going to a specific route after a login is nice but it leads to a poor UX when  the user tries to access a deep link that requires auth. Then you force them to login but don't take them to the deep link after. I have an [example router.js file](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/08/meteor-build-clean-easy-to-maintain.html) that covers this among other points. This is combined with `Accounts.onLogin` and `Meteor.logout` hooks as per @challett's answer to always take the user to the *expected* place.

Comment: Many thanks for your links. I read it with great interest. How could you use the roles into your router.js file?

Comment: There are already 2 roles in there (normal and admin) but I haven't incorporated [alanning:roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `Accounts.onLogin(function () {});` hook from Meteor instead of iron:router ([doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin)).  In this hook you can access Meteor.user() to check their role and change the action as needed.

Similarly, you can use the callback function in `Meteor.logout()` to handle any logic on logout as shown below:

```
Meteor.logout(function(err) {
  // logout logic here
});
```

If you want this logout hook to fire when you logout with {{> loginButtons}} on a certain template ie: `adminTemplate` then use the code below.  I have not tested this code snippet so minor adjustments may be needed.

```
Template.adminTemplate.events({
    'click #login-buttons-logout': function (event) {
        //add your custom logic on top of this
       //the default behaviour should still happen from meteor
    }
});
```

Comment: I have put the Accounts.onLogin on the client side and that seems to work but when I insert the Meteor.logout also on the client side (with a simple console output message for now), it does not seem to get called when I effectly logout from the admin section. Any idea why it is not triggered and where to put it so it gets called?

Comment: The logout callback acts a little bit differently than onLogin, you will need to add the callback everywhere that you call Meteor.logout() and you want the callback to fire.  So for this function to take effect in your admin section, wherever you are calling Meteor.logout() inside of it you will need to add the function that you wish to execute.

Comment: Since I'm using accounts-password and accounts-ui, I'm not explicitly calling it in my part of the code. It happens as part of the package. This means I would need to modify the package(eg find the function and customize the callback)? Or am I totally missing the point?

Comment: You can add an event on the click of the logout button that overrides the default behaviour of the button.  I will modify my answer to include this.

Comment: Many thanks. The modified answer indeed is what did the trick (I accepted the answer as it works perfectly). My only 'worry' though is that you have to repeat the same code in each template where the signout button is placed. I would rather prefer a global method.

Comment: You could add the event handler to the layout that you use (if you use one).

Comment: But I agree with you.  It is not the most convenient.  You could consider adding the userAccounts package found here: https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md .  I am using it in all of my projects and it provides much better customization than the standard accounts-ui.  It also gives you an onLogout hook.

Comment: The second code snippet worked well for me (with the Template.adminTemplate.events...) however that example is with a custom template defined.  If you are using the built in template that you would get with {{>loginButtons}}, use Template._loginButtonsLoggedInDropdown.events.  Additionally, if you want to redirect back to the "home page" which is typically the '/' route, you can use Iron Router package and do a Router.go('/');  (keeping in mind you must have a route defined for '/');